# How to do multiple things in a single line with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with the following columns:
['country code', 'transaction date', 'amount', 'distance', 'employee']

Im cleaning the data and but there are many things that I need to do that make the code messy. I'm working on google colab and currently im using one cell per step, and I was wondering if there is a way to do it all in just one.

This is what i currently have:

cell 1: i dont need all the columns, just three so i do:
**step1**

```
df = df[['transaction Date','amount','distance']
```

cell 2: the date is in the excel format (i.e  44327 = 2021-05-11) so I do the following to change the format
**step 2**

```
pd.to_datetime(data['Transaction Date'], unit='D', origin='1899-12-30')
```

cell 3 i want to filter with two conditions
**step 3**

```
df2=df[(df['distance'].notnull()) & (df['transaction Date'] > '2021-01-01') ]
```

cell4: i group by week
**step 4**

```
final_df = df2.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='transaction date', freq='W')])['values'].sum()
```

I'd love to be able to have just one cell that looks something like this>

```
df = step1.step2.step3.step4
```

Comment: You can put multiple lines of code in one cell, but I'd advise against going one step further and combining all of these into a single line of code. If each line of code is a different operation on your data, they probably belong on separate lines. Combining them will just make the code harder to read and debug later.

Comment: I fully support @BilltheLizard point. However you can combine cell 1 & 3 using [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). Then you can apply `groupby` to their output but the code will be messy.

Comment: You can write a function that does all those operations and returns the dataframe and then simply call that function...